# Which operators other than self-adjoint operators have no purely imaginary eigenvalues?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-equations, sp.spectral-theory

Given an operator mapping between suitable spaces, what is the condition that guarantees all eigenvalues have nonzero real part? Obviously self-adjointness implies all eigenvalues are real, but how about if we allow for the possibility of complex eigenvalues whilst imposing the condition that these cannot be purely imaginary?

I would guess this might be formulated as a condition on the self-adjoint and skew-self-adjoint parts of an operator, but can not see what it would be.

Comment: For matrices, at least, there are other classes: [M-matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix) and [Hurwitz stable matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix) (which you can find, for instance, with [Lyapunov stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability)).

Comment: if you give me an arbitrary square matrix, I don't see any way to determine whether an eigenvalue is on the imaginary axis other than trying to solve the characteristic equation; is there a shortcut?

Comment: A trivial condition: $iA$ is not self-adjoint with respect to any Hermitian form.

Comment: Alex, could you provide a link to the proof of this statement? In particular, I want a proof that applies to first order differential operators.

Comment: This just looks like the condition for an operator to not be skew-self-adjoint...

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev's condition is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: If you're looking at differential operators, you might have continuous spectrum.  Do you really mean **eigenvalues**, or do you want everything in the **spectrum** to have nonzero real part?

Comment: @Tobi Because eigenvalues of $iA$ are those of $A$ multiplied by~$i$. I agree, though, that it is not sufficient: $iA$ does not need to be diagonalizable at all.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you want, but a quasinilpotent operator without eigenvalues would seem to behave as requested in your title, and be very far from self-adjoint. Perhaps you could restrict yourself to certain kinds of operators? I think the question as posed, talking about general operators, is too broad to admit a useful answer

Comment: In particular I am interested in first order differential operators of the form $L=L_0+h$ where $L_0$ is first order self-adjoint, but the zeroth order term $h$ is not necessarily self-adjoint. Then yes, I am looking for the most general condition on $h$ that ensures everything in the spectrum has nonzero real part.

Comment: I was attempting a simpler version of this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/204769/pertubations-of-self-adjoint-first-order-operators , which no one has answered yet!

Comment: Dissipative and accretive operators are basic examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipative_operator .  Unfortunately the first-order operators you are interested in are unlikely to be in either class.

Comment: How is this question, which is far more general than the one you've just linked to, meant to be easier? Operators on Hilbert space can be very different from the ones described in your question!

Answer (score 2):

A unitary operator $A$ such that $A^4 - I$ is non-singular.

Comment: Don't you want $A^4-I$ to be nonsingular? Otherwise, $A$ could have some eigenvalues at $\pm i$ and others off the imaginary axis, whereas the question wants all the eignevalues off the imaginary axis.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, correct.